# How do I remove the "reverse character order" function?

Tags: javascript

How do I remove the function in this code to reverse the order of the characters? All I would like this function to do is replace all vowels imputed with "er".

Here is the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/R9e0JRce

```
// JavaScript Document
function flip() {
    var result = flipString(document.f.original.value);
    document.f.flipped.value = result;
}

function flipString(aString) {
    aString = aString.toLowerCase();
    var last = aString.length - 1;
    var result = "";
    for (var i = last; i >= 0; --i) {
        result += derpChar(aString.charAt(i))
    }
    return result;
}

function derpChar(c) {
    if (c == 'a') {
        return 'er'
    }
    else if (c == 'e') {
        return 'er'
    }
    else if (c == 'i') {
        return 'er' 
    }
    else if (c == 'o') {
        return 'er'
    }
    else if (c == 'u') {
        return 'er'
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: If you click on the question mark above the editor and on "code" you get information about how to format code properly. You can find this information also here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: I tried bypassing the "for (var i = last; i >= 0; --i)", which I assume is the troublesome function. It just broke the function. I have very minimum knowledge in this type of coding.      @felix, thank you for assisting me with that.

Comment: Instead of iterating over the string from the end to the beginning, iterate over it from the beginning to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is replace a set of characters, it could be done easily using a regular expression:

```
var str = 'abcdef';
var output = str.replace( /[aeiou]/g, 'er' );
```

result: `erbcderf`

more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)